# Is there an apache module or a server setting that will block apache benchmark

Tags: apache-2.2, ab

I was trying to perform apache benchmark on one of the server. However, the apache benchmark will always getting a timeout error.

I was wondering is there a module (like mod security) or a setting (like firewall) that blocking this?

curl is fine.

ab command:

> ab -n 10 -c 10 http://some.host/

from my local network, results:

> Benchmarking some.host (be patient)...Send request failed!
>   apr_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
>   Total of 1 requests completed

from another server in the same network with the server I want to benchmark:

> apr_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)

Comment: That is unlikely to be the problem What ab command line parameters are you using? What errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turn outs is a bug on apache benchmark v2.3
replace with siege is working fine.